# Difference between apachectl and apache2

Tags: apache

I have tried to restart my Apache server, I am new to this. 
I am curious to know
what does apache2 restart does?
what does apachectl restart do?

Comment: Please provide the path to both commands, and what OS you're using. A blind guess is your "apache2" command is from your distribution, and it calls out the "apachectl" command.

Comment: Under Debian for instance `/etc/init.d/apache2` is a script using the script `/usr/sbin/apachectl` which calls the symlink `/usr/sbin/apache2` which links to either the worker or prefork apache2 binary in `/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-(prefork|worker|event)/apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Ubuntu or the likes, a `man apache2` indicates the following:

> In  general,  apache2  should  not  be  invoked directly, but rather
>   should be invoked via /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl.

FYI: apachectl is an alias of apache2ctl nowadays

As a best practice, it is advised to issue `sudo apache2ctl graceful`

The **graceful** argument, as is intended by its meaning, offers a more stable way to restart the apache process by letting its child processes finish ongoing tasks before reloading the configurations.

cf `man apache2ctl`

restart:

> Restarts the Apache daemon by sending it a SIGHUP.

graceful:

> Gracefully  restarts the Apache daemon by sending it a SIGUSR1.  If
>   the daemon is not running, it is started.  This differs from a normal
>   restart in that currently open connections are
>                        not aborted.

[Here is a reference about signalling SIGUSR1 as opposed to SIGHUP.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825359/995072)